# How to rollback unwanted migration

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma

After executing `prisma migrate dev --name some_change_description` command successfully when working locally in my dev environment, there's any convenient way to roll it back? Besides handling the DB manually and deleting migration files and changes, there's a more convenient way?

Specifically, I'm working with postgress DB as my underlying DB

Comment: Just to confirm, did you had a look at this moving migrations backward guide: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/production-troubleshooting#moving-backwards-and-reverting-all-changes ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way in my mind at this point is to delete de last migration folder and run these commands:

1. `migrate reset` to reset the database and all data.
2. `migrate dev` to create a new migration with the correct scheme.